# Integrating Zio-Kafka Consumers with Zio-Json deserializer

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, zio, zio-streams

I'm studying the library `zio-kafka`, and I want to use `zio-json` to deserialize messages' values in JSON format.

I have a simple case class together with its decoder and encoder:

```scala
case class Player(name: String, score: Int)
object Player {
  implicit val decoder: JsonDecoder[Player] = DeriveJsonDecoder.gen[Player]
  implicit val encoder: JsonEncoder[Player] = DeriveJsonEncoder.gen[Player]
}
```

Right now, I created a `Serde` starting from a `Serde.string` that uses the above decoder / encoder:

```scala
val playerSerde: Serde[Any, Player] = Serde.string.inmapM { playerAsString =>
  ZIO.fromEither(playerAsString.fromJson[Player].left.map(new RuntimeException(_)))
} { playerAsObj =>
  ZIO.effect(playerAsObj.toJson)
}
```

Is it correct? Is there any other (better) approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `.getOrElse` as I think it makes the intent a bit clearer and avoids a naked access to the left field:

```scala
  val playerSerde: Serde[Any, Player] = Serde.string.inmapM { playerAsString =>
    ZIO.effectTotal(playerAsString.fromJson[Player].getOrElse(throw new Error))
  }(playerAsObj => ZIO.effect(playerAsObj.toJson))
```

I also assumed that you meant `.fromJson[Player]` as I didn't see a `Match` class anywhere in your question.

Comment: Gosh! You're right. I fixed the code in my question :) So, other than the “either” type mapping, is anything just fine?

Comment: Well perhaps we'll get a ZIO graybeard to weigh in with a more elegant solution but otherwise I think it's fine.

Comment: I don't think they exist ;)